# Azure File Share Create Directory

Tags: azure, azure-storage-files

I'm reviewing Azure File Share service. I wanted to determine what is required to create a directory. There is nothing explicit to configuring for this type of activity - so I just attempted to run a test scenario to create a directory. The directory is to be created at the root. With the code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connect);
CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference("fileaccess");
if (fileShare.Exists())
{
   CloudFileDirectory rootDirectory = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
   if (rootDirectory.Exists())
   {                        
     CloudFileDirectory customDirect = 
         rootDirectory.GetDirectoryReference("TEST");
     if (!customDirect.Exists())
     {
        rootDirectory.Create();
     }
   }
}
```

The result is the following error:

> > > > The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.<<<

I assumed it was a configuration on Azure - but I cannot see where on Azure I can allow this operation.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed

**Root Cause:**

I am sure that 405 error occurred in the code line `rootDirectory.Create();`. Azure doesn't allow us to create root directory, so it is not accepted by Azure server.

**Solution:**

According to your code logic, it seems that you want to create **customDirect**, so please change the code as following:

```
if (!customDirect.Exists())
{
   customDirect.Create();
}
```